# Injecting bean into default constructor

Tags: java, spring

Lets say i have a class like this :

```
public class A {

 private B b;

 public A() {

 }

 // Some code calling methods in b.
}
```

How can i inject an instance of B into A via XML configuration without adding a parameterized constructor in Spring ?

Can i have both parameterized constructor and a setter as well ?

```
 public class A {

     private B b;

     public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
     }

     public void setB(B b) {
         this.b = b;
     }
     // Some code calling methods in b.
    }
```

Edit : Thanks for all the answers. My actual problem is that i have a class like this :

public class A {

```
 private B b;

 public A(B b) {
    this.b = b;
 }
 // Some code calling methods in b.
}
```

and i want to have a default constructor for the above class without removing the parameterized constructor for backward compatibility reasons.

So ,

1. Does the bean get injected automatically into the default constructor when i add one ? Or should i have additional configuration in the XML file to inject it into it ?
2. If i add a setter what additional configuration changes should i make in the XML and how ?

Consider that i have an xml file as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="name"
          class="A">
        <constructor-arg ref="B" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via [Setter Injection](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-basic-setter-injection.html). For this, you need to add a setter method for your member field `b`

> Can i have both parameterized constructor and a setter as well ?

Yes you can have.

If the parameterized constructor is the **only constructor** in your bean, then you should go with 
constructor injection.

else create **non-argument default constructor** (along with the parameterized constructor) for your class and go with setter OR constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

If we are not allowed to change this class then there is no way, otherwise we can use Spring's Autowired annotation

```
public class A {
   @Autowired
   private B b
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The B object cannot be available in the constructor. The best option is to inject it and use a `@PostConstruct` method to initialize the bean. To inject the bean `b`, setter injection as mentionned by sanbhat. Alternatively, you could also use [annotation-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) and simply add a `@Inject` or `@Autowired` annotation to the B field and define your bean B in the XML configuration.

```
public class A {

 @Inject
 private B b;

 @PostConstruct
 public init() {
    // inititalization code...
 }

 // Some code calling methods in b.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may pass the bean class B id to Class A via `<constructor-arg>` tag like this in (for example beans.xml)

```
<bean id="a" class="ClassA">
    <constructor-arg ref="beanB"/>
</bean>
<bean id="beanB" class="com.tutorialspoint.SpellChecker">
   </bean>
```

the following url may helps you alot in this regard

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/constructor_based_dependency_injection.htm
[edited]